# nginx-ingress on GKE fails to route to path for configured service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, networking, google-cloud-platform, nginx-ingress

I am trying to configure an nginx ingress for a GKE cluster and define a path on a configured subdomain. It seems that even if I am able to successfully ping the host, and the domain binding is done correctly, I keep getting a 404 back whenever I try to access the configured path.

My goal is to be able to have a single static IP configured for my ingress controller and expose multiple services on different paths.

Below you can find my deployment files - one more thing that I would add is that I am using Terraform to automate the configuration and deployment of GCP and Kubernetes resources.

After the GKE cluster is successfully provisioned, I first deploy the official nginx-ingress controller from [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) - below my Terraform script that configures and deploys the controller with a custom static IP that I provisioned on GCP.

```
resource "helm_release" "nginx" {
  name  = "nginx"
  chart = "nginx-stable/nginx-ingress"
  timeout = 900

  set {
    name = "controller.stats.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.type"
    value = "LoadBalancer"
  }

  set {
    name  = "controller.service.loadBalancerIP"
    value = "<MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>"
  }
}
```

Below my ingress configuration that I also deploy via Terraform:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
  wait_for_load_balancer = true

  metadata {
    name = "app-ingress"

    annotations = {
        "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx"
        "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/"
        "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name": <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>
    }
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      host = custom.my_domain.com
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "app-service"
            service_port = 5000
          }

          path = "/app"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the resulting ingress configuration as taken from GCP:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-14T20:28:41Z"
  generation: 7
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: HIDDEN
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/app-ingress
  uid: HIDDEN
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custom.my_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /app
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>
```

And the output for the `kubectl describe ingress app-ingress` command:

```
Name:             app-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (192.168.10.8:8080)
Rules:
  Host                  Path  Backends
  ----                  ----  --------
  custom.my_domain.com
                        /app   app-service:5000 (192.168.10.11:5000)
Annotations:            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
                        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------          ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  AddedOrUpdated  16m (x6 over 32m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Configuration for default/app-ingress was added or updated
```

I deployed the application that I am trying to expose by using the following configuration files:

**pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: app-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: default
```

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: app-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: app-pvc
      containers:
      - name: app-container
        image: "eu.gcr.io/<PROJECT_ID>/<IMAGE_NAME>:VERSION_TAG"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5000
        livenessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 20
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/data"
            name: app-pvc
```

Everything gets deployed successfully, as I am able to directly connect to the application locally via the configured service by running the following command:

```
kubectl port-forward service/app-service 5000:5000
```

This allows me to access the application in my browser and everything works as intended.

To make sure that `<MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>` that I configured is properly bound to `custom.my_domain.com`, I tried to ping the host and I do get the right response back:

```
ping custom.my_domain.com

Pinging custom.my_domain.com [<MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=113
Reply from <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=113
Reply from <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=113
Reply from <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=113

Ping statistics for <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 36ms, Maximum = 45ms, Average = 38ms
```

Even if everything appears to be working as intended, whenever I try to navigate to `custom.my_domain.com/app` in my browser, I keep getting the following response in my browser, even after waiting for more than 30m to make sure that the ingress configuration has been properly registered on GCP:
[image]

And this is the entry that shows up in the logs of my nginx-controller pod:

```
<HIDDEN_LOCAL_IP> - - [14/Apr/2021:21:18:10 +0000] "GET /app/ HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0" "-"
```

**UPDATE #1**

It appears that if I update my ingress to directly expose the targeted service on the `/` path, it works as intended. Below the updated configuration. Still, it appears that if I try to set any other path, it does not work.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-14T20:28:41Z"
  generation: 7
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: HIDDEN
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/app-ingress
  uid: HIDDEN
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custom.my_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>
```

**Update #2**

After going through the materials shared by @jccampanero in the comments section, I was able to get a working configuration.

Instead of using [nginx-stable](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) which is referenced on the official nginx website, I used the one [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) and updated my Terraform script accordingly to use this one with the exact same configuration I had.

Afterwards, I had to update my ingress by following the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) - below the updated configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: static-ip-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-14T20:28:41Z"
  generation: 7
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: HIDDEN
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/app-ingress
  uid: HIDDEN
spec:
  rules:
  - host: custom.my_domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /app(/|$)(.*)
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <MY_STATIC_IP_ADDRESS>
```

Comment: I think the problem can be related with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation. Is everything working fine without that annotation? Probably not, but as you can see in the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target), starting in version 0.22.0 of the Nginx ingress controller the behavior of the annotation changed because of the use of capture groups, it may be relevant to your problem.

Comment: I initially tried to deploy it without that annotation, but the behavior is exactly the same. I already went through the docs you shared, but could not find a proper solution. What I am also experimenting with, even if it is not the solution I am looking for, is to have a single service exposed per ingress configuration and use multiple static ip addresses, one for every service that I expose. This would potentially lead to exposing them on individual subdomains. Still, as mentioned, this would be just an experiment to see if I can get an ingress to work on my subdomain.

Comment: @jccampanero I just tried redeploying the entire stack with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root` annotation, and I get the exact same behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you very much for the feedback. I am sorry @vladzam, yes, probably the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root` annotation will have no effect in your case. I wanted to mean that probably the problem has to do with the definition of the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation, you are providing '/', but probably you need to provide something like `/$1`. I will try deploying a new version of the controller in my local environment and see. Any way, it seems that now there are several versions of the Nginx ingress controller and some of them (cont)

Comment: do not handle the rewrite target annotation properly in some situations: please, consider read this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535281/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-rewrite-target-annotation-breaking), and the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5756), and this two [1](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/962) [2](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/community/issues/1274). With the exception of the mentioned annotation, I think your setup looks fine: having said that, please, I do not want to confuse you,(cont)

Comment: honestly, it is being a long time without using the controller especially in gke.

Comment: @jccampanero thanks a lot for your support on this question - I really appreciate it. I just tried it with the `/$2` rewrite target, but I get the same behavior (404 redirect) as with any other path when using the `/` rewrite target. In terms of the nginx controller version, I am installing it from the `stable` channel (1.18.0 as per the official nginx website)

Comment: You are welcome @vladzam. I am sorry to hear that it does not work with capture group placeholders neither. Have you tried to use the nginx ingress controller version suggested in the above mentioned [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535281/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-rewrite-target-annotation-breaking) instead of the one you installed? As you can see in the [nginx-ingress docs](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress), it seems to be deprecated in favor of [ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx)

Comment: @jccampanero I just finished reading through all the useful material you shared and I was actually able to get it to work! Thank you very much once more. Can you please write an answer based on what I documented under Update #2 so that I can accept your answer to award the bounty?

Comment: Hi @vladzam.That is great!! I am very happy that you were able to find the solution. Thank you very much, I really appreciate it: I created the answer although you deserve all the credit, you were the person that find the actual solution. Thank you very much again. Please, do not hesitate to contact me again if you think I can be of any help, I will be glad to help you if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the question comments and in the question itself, very well documented by @vladzam, two are the reasons of the problem.

On one hand, the nginx ingress controller available through the Helm `stable` channel seems to be [deprecated](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) in favor of the new `ingress-nginx` controller - please, see [the Github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx%60) and the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

On the other, it seems to be a problem related to the definition of the `Rewrite target` annotation. According to the [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target):

> Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` are not backwards compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and beyond, any substrings within the request URI that need to be passed to the rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a capture group.

As a consequence, it is necessary to modify the definition of the ingress resource to take into account this change. For instance:

```yaml
$ echo '
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
' | kubectl create -f -
```

The question itself provides the exact ingress resource definition.