# Why can't load balancer connect to service in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying an application on GKE cluster and try to deploy a load balancer to make clients able to call this application.

My application spec is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: api
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: docker-sa
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: zhaoyi0113/rancher-go-api
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  selector:
    name: api
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
```

It listens on the port 8080 and a service open port 80 and use the targetPort 8080 to connect to the application.

And I have a ingress spec:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sidecar
  namespace: default
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: api
      port:
        number: 80
```

After deploy, I am able to see the `ip address` from `kubectl get ingress`. But when I send a request to the ip, I got 502 error.

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME      CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS           PORTS   AGE
sidecar   <none>   *       107.178.245.193   80      28m

$ kubectl describe ingress sidecar
Name:             sidecar
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          107.178.245.193
Default backend:  api:80 (10.0.1.14:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     api:80 (10.0.1.14:8080)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s1-5ae02eec-default-api-80-28d7bbec":"Unknown"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       29m                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m" created
  Normal  Sync       28m                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m" created
  Normal  Sync       28m                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-krllp0c9-default-sidecar-9a9n4r5m" created
  Normal  IPChanged  28m                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now 107.178.245.193
  Normal  Sync       3m51s (x7 over 29m)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Below is the curl error response:

```
$ curl -i http://107.178.245.193/health
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 332
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2022 10:40:31 GMT


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

When I describe the service `api`, I got below error:

```
$ kubectl describe service api
Name:                     api
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress": true}
                          cloud.google.com/neg-status: {"network_endpoint_groups":{"80":"k8s1-29362abf-default-api-80-f2f1248a"},"zones":["australia-southeast2-a"]}
                          field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: [{"port":30084,"protocol":"TCP","serviceName":"default:api","allNodes":true}]
Selector:                 name=api
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.3.253.54
IPs:                      10.3.253.54
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30084/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.1.17:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age   From            Message
  ----     ------        ----  ----            -------
  Warning  AttachFailed  7s    neg-controller  Failed to Attach 2 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-29362abf-default-api-80-f2f1248a" in zone "australia-southeast2-a"): googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.ipAddress': '10.0.1.18'. Specified IP address 10.0.1.18 doesn't belong to the (sub)network default or to the instance gke-gcp-cqrs-gcp-cqrs-node-pool-6b30ca5c-41q8., invalid
  Warning  RetryFailed   7s    neg-controller  Failed to retry NEG sync for "default/api-k8s1-29362abf-default-api-80-f2f1248a--/80-8080-GCE_VM_IP_PORT-L7": maximum retry exceeded
```

Does anyone know what could be the root course?

Comment: at a first glance, it appears you might be missing some annotations on your Ingress resource definition; I also struggled a bit the first time I configured an Ingress on GKE; for my particular scenario, I was using the NGINX ingress controller - here is the post, maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67099282/nginx-ingress-on-gke-fails-to-route-to-path-for-configured-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a new GKE cluster and tried setting up the same resources you are configuring. However, I used the following image for the container `gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0`. Everything else remains the same - leaving the `gcp-setup.yaml` file I used below for reference.

**gcp-setup.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  selector:
    name: api
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sidecar
  namespace: default
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: api
      port:
        number: 80
```

There is also a small thing I had to change in your configuration, which is the `annotation` block - when I first tried to apply your configuration, I got the below error. Hence, I had to adjust the `annotation` entry to be `annotations`.

```
> kubectl apply -f gcp-setup.yaml
deployment.apps/api created
error: error validating "gcp-setup.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.metadata): unknown field "annotation" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Afterwards, I was able to successfully provision all of the resources, and your configuration worked perfectly fine. It took around 3 minutes I believe for the Ingress resource to get an IP address assigned (masked as `XX.XXX.XXX.XX` below).

```
> kubectl get pods
NAME                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
api-7d6fdd9845-8dwqc   1/1     Running   0          7m13s

> kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
api          NodePort    10.36.4.150   <none>        80:30142/TCP   7m1s
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.36.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        12m

> kubectl get ingress
NAME      CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
sidecar   <none>   *       XX.XXX.XXX.XX   80      7m18s

> kubectl describe ingress
Name:             sidecar
Namespace:        default
Address:          XX.XXX.XXX.XX
Default backend:  api:80 (10.32.0.10:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     api:80 (10.32.0.10:8080)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s1-05f3ce8b-default-api-80-82dd4d72":"HEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                 From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       7m13s               loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex" created
  Normal  Sync       7m10s               loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex" created
  Normal  Sync       6m59s               loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-9k4w4ytx-default-sidecar-9m5g4dex" created
  Normal  IPChanged  6m59s               loadbalancer-controller  IP is now XX.XXX.XXX.XX
  Normal  Sync       28s (x6 over 8m3s)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

After the Ingress resource became healthy, I was able to navigate in my browser to the assigned IP address `XX.XXX.XXX.XX` and got a successful response back from the workload I deployed (`gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0`).

**Browser Output**

```
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: api-7d6fdd9845-8dwqc
```

As a conclusion, make sure to update your Service definition from `metadata.annotation` to `metadata.annotations`. It was the only change I had to do to make your configuration work. Furthermore, I recommend turning resource definition validation on to make sure that you catch such errors when defining new resources.

If the error still persists, I would recommend running `kubectl describe ingress sidecar` and analyze the output, assuming it is related to the Ingress resource definition.

**EDIT1**

To make sure that this is not a zone-related issue, I provisioned a VPC-native, Public cluster in the same zone that you are using (`australia-southeast2-a`). I then applied the same configuration, and it was successful, thus ruling out the zone-related topic.

Based on the additional information you included in the post, my best guess for some potential root causes for the Service error you're getting when running `kubectl describe service` would be:

- Your GKE cluster is not [VPC-native](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) - I see this is a core requirement to be able to leverage NEG
- Your GKE cluster has been provisioned as a Private cluster, and as a consequence, NEG tries to assign an IP address from the available Private subnet ranges. This would explain the `10.0.1.18` IP address that NEG tries to assign to the resource definition

Comment: I tried your method, I got the ip address but when send request to the IP, it responses `502 Bad Gateway`. It seems the ingress doesn't connect to my container

Comment: what port does the `zhaoyi0113/rancher-go-api` image expose? it can be that the workload itself does not open port `8080` which you are using. I would recommend making sure that the port you are running your workload on in the image is the same as the one you are exposing via the kubernetes deployment. Additionally, can you also please update your post with the logs from your ingress resource definition and ingress controller? to see if there are any errors there

Comment: I have put all the details on the post. I can't see any different with yours. but don't know why it still doesn't work

Comment: could you please try and use the image I am using (`gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0`)? this will allow you to validate if it is related to the image you are using or the workload configuration

Comment: yes, I have tried but same error. I found that describe the service gives me some error. I have put in the post. Do you see this error before?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with some additional info based on the output you added